# Only title gets loaded when pushing uiViewController onto NavigationController - iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have a strange issue going on which I can't fathom. I have a number of uiViewControllers which I'm pushing onto a NavigationController - all fairly regular stuff. It's a bit of a drill-down application so after you've moved through 3 screens, the next view to be pushed doesn't actually appear - only the title changes in the Nav Bar. I'm pushing it the same way as all the others:

```
DisplayViewController *tempDispController = [[DisplayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DisplayVC" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tempDispController animated:YES];
    [tempDispController release];
```

The new title is set in the ViewDidLoad of the new ViewController - and that does animate in, but the actual view is still the old one.

EDIT: Forgot to say that it does load fine occasionally. Usually the first time but then not the next few times. Sometimes not even the first time.

Any ideas?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the view controller *is* being pushed onto the stack, but its view has no content.

Comment: Sorry - I meant to include the fact that it does load occasionally. Usually the first time is fine, but then not again for a while. I've updated my original question! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.. the viewController calling it was running a synchronous network call which hadn't completed by the time I was calling the next viewcontroller..

So, just made it an asynchronous connection and waited for the response before moving on. Also makes it better for showing progress to the user - and error handling.

Thanks for the responses though!